# Jump to another case in PHP switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

Say I have something like this:

```
switch ($_GET['func']) {
    case 'foo':
        dobar();
        break;
    case 'orange':
        if ($_GET['aubergine'] == 'catdog') {
            // **DO DEFAULT OPTION**
        } else {
            dosomethingElse();
        }
        break;
    default:
        doDefault();
}
```

How can I jump to the `default` case from the marked spot in `case 'orange'`?

Comment: Why can't you just call `doDefault()`?

Comment: I genuinely laughed at `$_GET['aubergine'] == 'catdog'`. That's some wonderful naming you've got going on there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
switch($_GET['func']) {
  case 'foo':
    dobar();
    break;

  case 'orange':
    if($_GET['aubergine'] != 'catdog') {
        dosomethingElse();
        break;
    }

  default:
    doDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's what I was hunting around for and kept me from having to post a question. Thanks! Very much appreciated.

Comment: I do this very same thing sometimes. When I do, I usually add a "//Fallthrough" comment where the case break should be, so I (and other people looking at the code) can know it was done on purpose, not just an accidentally missing break.

Answer (score 11):

Yo dawg, you can use a cool new feature called the [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php).

```
<?php
$func = "orange";
function doDefault() { echo "yeehaw!"; return; }
function dobar() { return; }
function dosomethingElse() { return; }

switch ($func) {
    case 'foo':
        dobar();
        break;
    case 'orange':
        if (true) {
            goto defaultlabel;
        } else {
            dosomethingElse();
        }
        break;
    default:
    defaultlabel:
        doDefault();
}
```

Comment: You can but a lot of programmers would shout something about writing spaghetti code :p P.S: Upvoted for the "Yo dawg".

Comment: Quite, I remember the first time I had to unlearn the goto command. I don't want to go there again!

I think the main problem here is how the SWITCH actually works. In my mind, you should be able to simply omit the break, and then the default would run. However, PHP will execute every command after a successful case, even if its in another case. That to me is odd.

Comment: @Puzbie this happens because `switch` statement despite having a similar usage with `if`, is basically a wrapper for a convenient form of `goto` operator construction. Although its 'labels' (`case XX:`) aren't the same labels of `goto` and we **cannot** use `goto` to jump to switch cases.