# Php traverse through the switch, and pass through

Tags: php, switch-statement

is it possible in php to do something like this:

```
switch ($option) {

    case "a":
      if($val == 7) {
          include("page.php");
      } else {
          "go to default case";
      }
    break;

    case "b":
      include("somefile.php");
    break;

    default:
     include("404.php");
    break;

}
```

In the above case "a" if $val == 7 include page.php otherwize go to default switch case

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859171/php-switch-to-other-case-option

Comment: Actually, I have found the answer using goto 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237982/php-is-it-possible-to-jump-from-one-case-to-another-inside-a-switch

Comment: That is probably the worst option there is.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a hackish way (I would look for a better way) but it would look like this:

```
switch ($option) {

    case "b":
      include("somefile.php");
    break;

    case "a":
      if($val == 7) {
          include("page.php");
          break;
      } else {
          // go to default case
      }

    default:
      include("404.php");
    break;
}
```

`break` when `$val == 7` or else don't `break` and drop into the default.

An even more hackish way IMO would be `goto`:

```
switch ($option) {

    case "a":
      if($val == 7) {
          include("page.php");
      } else {
          goto notfound;
      }
    break;

    case "b":
      include("somefile.php");
    break;

    default:
    notfound:
     include("404.php");
    break;

}
```

So in short, no you can't jump to another case without falling into it or `goto`.  I would probably create a function and call it in both places.

Comment: This works, just make sure you don't add another `case` between `"a"` and `default` :-)

Comment: That does not answer the question. Is it possible to redirect from one swithc case to another