# Is it posible to execute two cases of the switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have something like this

```
switch($m){
    case 1:
        some code
        break;
    case 2:
        some code
        break;
    case 3:
        some code
        break;
}
```

I need that then case 2 executes it will go back and execute case 1. or then case 3 executes i need it to go back and execute case 1.

Is it possible to do?
Thank you!

Comment: why not create functions for each case, then call them as needed

Comment: there are some good guesses below, but i bet there are options not even using `switch\case` at  all. We simply don't have enough information to give a good answer to this question.

Comment: a (very bad) option, assuming you are using c/c++, is to use "labels" and "goto" statements. But see @Dagon's comment. you *shouldn't* be jumping around in a switch statement like that. refactor to use if/else + helper functions if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: switch to other case option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859171/php-switch-to-other-case-option)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, something like this should work for you:

```
function duck($m)
{
  switch($m){
      case 1:
          //some code
          break;
      case 2:
          duck(1);
          break;
      case 3:
          duck(1);
          break;
  }
}


duck(2);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you set it up right:

```
switch($var){
    case 1:
        some code 1;
    case 2:
        some code 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        some code 3;
    default
        some code 4;
        break;
}
```

Basically, it will keep going down the flow of the switch til it reaches a break. So, in this example, case 2 will execute code 2, but case one will execute first code 1 THEN code 2, because there is no break. Same thing for case 3 and default: case 3 would hit both some code 3 and some code 4.